# Rename individual variables and assign them values from a List with a For loop C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, variables, rename

I have a list of items (Tlist) and I want to assign them consecutively to individual variables (T0-T4) which can be named also consecutively.

```
        List<int?> Tlist = new List<int?>();

        Tlist.Add(1);
        Tlist.Add(4);
        Tlist.Add(3);
        Tlist.Add(1);
        Tlist.Add(5);

        int? T0 = null;
        int? T1 = null;
        int? T2 = null;
        int? T3 = null;
        int? T4 = null;
```

So I can do:

```
        int g = 0;
        T0 = Tlist[g++];
        T1 = Tlist[g++];
        T2 = Tlist[g++];
        T3 = Tlist[g++];
        T4 = Tlist[g++];
```

But, how can I rename the variables T0-T4 within a Forloop to deliver the same output without having to rewrite each of the variables? I would like something like:

```
        int g = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Tlist.Count; i++)
        {
            Tg++ = Tlist[g++];
        }
```

So the output is:

```
        T0 = 1
        T1 = 4
        T2 = 3
        T3 = 1
        T4 = 5
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you make a collection with the individual variables? If you can, then the problem is solved already. If you can't: Why not?

Comment: You don't. You simply don't. (Well, you actually can't. Though luck...) Use an array or other appropriate collection (like List<T>, as you did with _Tlist_) to store a _collection_ (!) of values...

Comment: @ Guillermo Gerard I can not make a collection. T0-T4 need to be individual variables

Comment: Well, if you really need T0-T4, then you can only do what you already did; assigning each of those variables individually and explicitly. (You wouldn't need `g`, though. You could simply do `T0 = Tlist[0];`, `T1 = Tlist[1]; ...`)

Comment: It looks like you want to keep collection, but access items via key. Which is `Dictionary<>`.

Comment: @fubo, OP said T0-T4 are variables, not fields or properties. Based on this, reflection wouldn't really help. (But if they would be fields/properties, reflection could help. But i wouldn't really suggest this at this point, because to me it looks like the issue is just a symptom of poor/wrong design)

Comment: The problem is that I have to export the variables individually and this is just an example, the list is longer.

Comment: What do you mean with "export"? Usually you don't export variables, you export values. I don't know your scenario nor requirements, but i have confidence that your detour through some T0-T4 variables would not really be necessary for export and that the desired export result can be achieved in a different, easier manner

Comment: You seriously need to give more information as to what you are trying to achieve otherwise it's stands to be a XY problem which has no correct answer probably

Comment: @Roblogic, If your problem is how to export individual variables, ask that instead. You are looking at it in the wrong way right now.

Comment: Even if you *could* dynamically rename these variables inside a loop, how would you *use* them without knowing their names?

Answer (score 1):

You seriously don't need that and rather can just have an `int?[]` for that purpose as already commented. You can just say

```
var arr = Tlist.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is one way if you make your `TX`s to properties

```
typeof(myClass).GetProperty("T" + i).SetValue(myClassInstance, i);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/qEoaok

If this question isn't about technical possibilities and you want to use this in your application, you should better find a different approach.